# Phonegap 3.7.0 Flashlight Plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I simply want to add the Flashlight plugin (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/294) but it doesn't work. I have no error and it doesn't show in the plugins list on build.phonegap.com.

I added this line of code in the config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight" version="1.0" />
```

But it still doesn't work.

Here is the whole config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.flashy.ltescari" version="1.0.0">
<version>0.0.1</version>
<description>A flashlight application.</description>
<author href="" email="luca.tescari@hotmail.com">Luca Tescari</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
<preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" version="0.2.11" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.2" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" version="0.2.11" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" version="0.2.13" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" version="0.2.10" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" version="0.3.9" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" version="0.2.10" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.6" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" version="0.3.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight" version="1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.13" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" version="0.3.3" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" version="0.3.11" />
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
<icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
<access origin="*"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: did you check the latest version 2.0.1 <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight" version="2.0.1" />

Comment: @Ashokbharathi Yes, i've just tried this, but it doesn't work.

I also have noticed that when I change the "version" in the XML file that it doesn't affect the version number on the build.phonegap settings page.

Comment: please refer this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml. in your file you included the version two times also the Application name is missing

Comment: @Ashokbharathi I used the template XML now, and for debugging purposes I changed the description. Sadly the description on the build.phonegap page is still the default "Hello World" description.

Comment: @LucaTescari Are you sure you put the updated `config.xml` in the correct place? It looks like you upload outdated file to PhoneGap Build.

Comment: @Amin Yes, I've created a new project with the Phonegap desktop application, so i guess it's in the right place. (It's in the Projects root folder)

Comment: @LucaTescari I see. Do you create a zip file from the parent folder? maybe you zip the containing files and not the parent folder.

Comment: @Amin Yes i noticed that i zipped the containing files and not the parent folder. It's such a stupid mistake and took forever until i noticed it :/

Anyway thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of compiling it online i've now put it on github and added it as a public app on build.phongeap. Finally it works! I have no idea why this makes a difference but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.flashlight" version="2.0.3" />
```

Comment: This does not work. It is the same as the first comment only with the newer version.